# How to return data from page.evaluate() in Puppeteer, when there is Promise.all() inside browser in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, puppeteer

I want to find average color of all images in the page. I am using Puppeteer to launch chromium and then run javascript inside browser.

Problem is that I am using Promies.all to asynchronously calculate all colors inside browser.

I want to return calculated image colors to page.evaluate. How can I do that? Is it possible?

Following code does not work, because imgcolors is no defined obviously, it is returned inside Promise.all callback.

```
   const returned = await page.evaluate(async () => {
   const fac = new FastAverageColor();
   const imgs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img'));
   const imgpromises = imgs.map(img => fac.getColorAsync(img.src));


   Promise.all(imgpromises).then(imgcolors => { return imgcolors;});

   return {
     document:{
       height: document.body.scrollHeight, 
       width:document.body.scrollWidth 
     },
     imgcolors:imgcolors
   };
 });
```

I have tried following:

```
Promise.all(imgpromises).then(imgcolors => { 
      
      return {
        elements:elements, 
        document:{
          height: document.body.scrollHeight, 
          width:document.body.scrollWidth 
        },
        imgcolors:imgcolors
      };
    });
```

Now I am not returing data to page.evaluate puppeteer function. So const returned is undefined.

How to do that? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [`page.evaluate`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) function, you can return a promise, which will resolve to a value. In this case `Promise.all` returns a promise, which you can chain to return the value you want. It'd look something like this:

```
const returned = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const fac = new FastAverageColor();
  const imgs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img'));
  const imgpromises = imgs.map(img => fac.getColorAsync(img.src));
  return Promise.all(imgpromises).then(imgcolors => { 
    return {
      document:{
        height: document.body.scrollHeight, 
        width: document.body.scrollWidth 
      },
      imgcolors: imgcolors
    };
  });
});
```

Alternatively, since you are using `async` functions, you can just use the `await` operator to wait for values to be resolved:

```
const returned = await page.evaluate(async () => {
  const fac = new FastAverageColor();
  const imgs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img'));
  const imgpromises = imgs.map(img => fac.getColorAsync(img.src));
  const imgcolors = await Promise.all(imgpromises);
  return {
    document:{
      height: document.body.scrollHeight, 
      width: document.body.scrollWidth 
    },
    imgcolors: imgcolors
  };
});
```

Note that [`page.evaluate`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) can only return [serializable values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description), i.e. things that can be `JSON.stringify`'d. It looks like `imgcolors` should be serializable, but in other cases, you might need to convert the values to something serializable.